# Mips program not printing the correct string

Tags: mips, converters, roman-numerals

I am creating a program to convert roman numerals. I am inputting letters(roman numerals) and the output should be the corresponding integer. When I enter a roman numeral it says that the number is 0 no matter what the number is. I think that it is skipping the rom function and just directly printing something out, but i can't seem to figure out why it is doing that.

```
  #Program to convert Roman numerals
  #Written by Naomi Gebremariam

  .data
  .align    2 
fprompt: .asciiz "Enter a Roman number: "
fanswer: .asciiz " The arabic notation of the roman numeral you entered is = \n"
  #----------------------------------Usual stuff at beginning of main---------------------------------------------------
  .text
  .globl main

  #takes the user input and puts it into registers, makes a call to check then prints result
main:               

  #get roman numeral inpuut from user

  li $s1,'I'     #load I into s0
  li $s2,'V'             
  li $s3,'X' 
  li $s4,'L'
  li $s5,'C'
  li $s6,'D'
  li $s7,'M'

  la $a0,fprompt
  li $v0,4
  syscall
  li $v0,51
  syscall

  jal rom

  #a0 has n (romnum)


  #print result   
  move $v0,$t1
  la $a0,fanswer         
  li $v0,1       
  syscall            
  li $v0,10          
  syscall   

  #have to store these so that the sequence can be calculated


  #-------------------------Function to check how many symbols are entered---------------------------------------


rom:     
  addi $sp, $sp, -8 #allocate stack space
  sw $ra, 0($sp) #store return address
  sw $s0, 4($sp)
  #------------function body--------------------------      

  #load roman numerals into registers for comparison
  move $s0,$v0
  beq $s1,$s0,one
  beq $s2,$a0,five
  beq $s3,$s0,ten 
  beq $s4,$s0,fifty
  beq $s5,$s0,hundred
  beq $s6,$s0,fivehun
  beq $s7,$s0,thousand


one:  
  li $t1,1

five:
  li $t1,5
  jr $ra

ten: 
  li $t1,10 #load 10 into result
  jr $ra

fifty:
  li $t1,50
  jr $ra

hundred:
  li $t1,100

fivehun: 
  li $t0,500

thousand:
  li $t1,1000

done:          
  lw $ra, 0($sp)
  lw $s0, 4($sp)
  addi $sp, $sp, 8 
  jr $ra
```

Comment: have you tried using the debugger ?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the lines:

```
li $v0,51
syscall
```

Is going to read an integer and put it in a0, but you are wanting to read a string that contains the roman number.

So you need somewhere to store that string, and then (if you are handling a single character number) need to get the first character out from that string.

Later in:

```
hundred:
  li $t1,100

fivehun: 
  li $t0,500

thousand:
  li $t1,1000
```

Anything that goes to these labels will end up setting t1 to 1000, as the code just falls through to the next statement, unlike what you had done to ones, tens etc.